# Do I need to pay tax if I use my own bank account for collected money for a booked hotel in the UK?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, vat

We are organizing an event in the UK  and we need to book a hotel for about 200 attendees.  The booking fee of about 4,000 pounds is to be shared by all the people. Since we have no company bank account nor a ticket sale system, we decided to use my personal bank account for collected money  and use it  to pay for the hotel.

All of the money will be temporarily stored in my bank account for several days and then there will be no money left in it.

The question  is whether I need to pay tax for collecting money from all attendees. The 4,000 pounds has already paid the VAT for the hotel.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you’re not making a profit there’s no tax to pay. (You might have to register for VAT if the total amount was over the threshold, but in this case it’s only about 5% of the threshold.) However, you would be well advised to keep all the paperwork to prove that you’re not doing it as a business and making a profit, in case HMRC query it.

Comment: What do you mean the threshold here, and is there a link for the 5% threshold?

Comment: @MingLi https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration-thresholds